# Visual Studio Emulator for Android: Catastrophic failure when trying to launch

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I recently installed the stand-alone Visual Studio Emulator for Android to use with Android Studio. However, when I try to launch an emulator, I get a dialog asking if I want to configure the emulator to connect to a network. If I select "No", the emulator launches and seems to work nicely but won't connect to the internet. If I select "Yes", I get the following error:

```
The emulator is unable to create the external network switches:

Something happened while creating a switch:
Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.

Ethernet port '{5A2CBD16-0961-475A-84AB-83B62B5376B4}'
bind failed: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF).
```

I only have a single network interface which is a wireless one.

I've tried removing all the virtual switches from Hyper-V manager, but that didn't work. I also tried to create a new internal switch manually, but that doesn't affect the problem either.

What could cause this problem? How could I get the emulator to launch with an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are unable to create the external switch. Try manually creating an external switch in Hyper-V Manager, and if you can, then delete all of your virtual switches in Hyper-V Manager, delete all VS Emulator VMs in Hyper-V Manager, and try starting the emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case I had sharing enabled on my wireless connection. Go into Network Connections, right click your wireless connection, go into the Properties, and under the Sharing tab make sure all the check boxes are unchecked.